# Name is not defined error

Tags: python, string

I am well aware that this is a noob question but i cant seem to find the solution, i'm very new to programming but eager to learn. I'm going through the first google clases in python and this is the error i get.

```
def both_ends(s):
  print s[0:2], s[3:5]
  return

x = input('...: ')
both_ends(x)

sergei@sergei-MS-7253:~/Desktop/p2$ python test2.py
...: haloj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 10, in <module>
    x = input('...: ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'haloj' is not defined
```

please explain what the problem is.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, [input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) takes a string that should be immediately executed. If you want to save the given input as a string (your intention), use [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem and helped me understand it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try `raw_input` instead of `input`.

To expand, you're probably reading a tutorial that assumes you're using Python 3.x, and you're probably using Python 2.x. In Python 2.x, `input` actually evaluates the text it gets, which means that it thinks `haloj` is a variable name; hence the `NameError`. In Python 3.x, `input` simply returns the text as a string.

Your other option is to enter `'haloj'` instead of `haloj`. (Note the added quotation marks.)

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.  When you use `input()`, python actually is doing an `eval(raw_input())` - so it is trying to call eval on what you input.  When you typed in 'haloj', python looked for a variable called `haloj`, which, of course, did not exist.